# Embedding YouTube video on a website dynamically using button click

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe

I need to embed YouTube video on my website.. It needs the user to input a YouTube link and on click of a button, the respective video should embed/appear in the website.I tried to dynamically link the src attribute of the iframe tag but i failed doing it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please share a minimal reproducible example here so that others can understand your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically create multiple youtube videos embedded to a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061462/how-to-dynamically-create-multiple-youtube-videos-embedded-to-a-page)

Answer (score 1):

you cant directly use a iframe for an youtube video, more on this here :
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

so what you can do is to enclose the iframe component in a div and show it when the button is clicked. like this :

`[codepen](https://codepen.io/ramu97/pen/ZVOger)`